# Generalized Hough Transform in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, hough-transform, opencv3.2

I was looking for Generalized Hought Transform in OpenCV, and I have found these two websites, talking about generalized Hough in OpenCV.

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/cudaimgproc/doc/hough.html#cuda-creategeneralizedhoughguil

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d15/group__cudaimgproc__hough.html

I understood should be Generalized Hough transform implemented in OpenCV. Or am I wrong? Is it going to be implemented in some oncoming version of OpenCV? I found nothing like documentation to this function, so is it just API for future versions? If it is implemented in OpenCV, could you please advise me where to look for documentation?

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is implemented GHT, you can find it in: samples/gpu/generalized_hough.cpp